# How to get button data-attribute value from Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to create a small font-awesone icon picker using bootstrap popover. Here is the HTML structure of the Popover Content.

```
<div class="popover-content">
    <div class="icon-container form-group">
        <div class="icons">
            <button data-icon="fa-500px" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-500px"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-adjust" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-adjust"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-adn" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-adn"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-align-center" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-align-center"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-align-justify" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-amazon" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-amazon"></i></button>
            <button data-icon="fa-ambulance" class="icon input-group"><i class="fa fa-ambulance"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, here is the jQuery..

```
$('.icons-wrapper').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('button.icon').on( 'click', function() {
        var selectedIcon = $(this).data('icon');
        console.log( 'The selected icon is: '+ selectedIcon);
    });
});
```

I am getting the error message..

```
ReferenceError: selectedIcon is not defined
```

The error remains even if I bind the click on document.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.icon', function () {
    var selectedIcon = $(this).data('icon');
    console.log( 'The selected icon is: '+ selectedIcon );
});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0zy53gLf/ Its working fine.

Comment: Okay, I got it working.. I had to wrap the events in a .each function.